# Getting parsererror in Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create a log in system with php, jquery, ajax, json, it validates if there are empty fields, but as soon as I complete and submit the form the ajax call fails, the console shows the json array in the response text, so the problem is not the php part, but it says parsererror, I don't know how to resolve this, I'm still a rookie. Here's my code:

### index.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/ajax/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/ajax/css/style.css"/>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>

        <section>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12" id="titulo">
                        <h3>Ajax Login</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
                        <form id="formulario" action="php/validator.php" method="post">
                            <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4" id="formPart">
                                <label for="user">Nombre de Usuario</label>
                                <input type="text" id="user" name="user" class="form-control">
                                <div class="user"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4" id="formPart">
                                <label for="pass">Nombre de Usuario</label>
                                <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" class="form-control">
                                <div class="pass"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4" id="formPart">
                                <input type="submit" value="Iniciar Sesión" class="btn btn-success">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4" id="response"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>


        <script src="/ajax/js/jquery2.js"></script>
        <script src="/ajax/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/ajax/js/ajax.js"></script>
        <script>

            $(document).ready(function(){

                setTimeout(function(){

                    $('#user').focus();

                }, 700);

            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

### validator.php

```
<?php 

if($_POST){

    $required = array('user', 'pass');
    $validation = array('user' => 'Debes Ingresar tu Nombre de Usuario', 'pass' => 'Debes Ingresar tu Contraseña');
    $error = array();
    $inputs = array();

    foreach($required as $key){ 
        if(array_key_exists($key, $_POST)){
            if(empty($_POST[$key])){
                $error[$key] = $validation[$key];
            }
            else{
                $inputs[$key] = $_POST[$key];
            }
        }
        else{
            $error[$key] = $validation[$key];
        }
    }

    if(!empty($error)){     
        $array = array('error' => true, 'fields' => $error);
    }
    else{
        $user = $inputs['user'];
        include 'log.php';
        if(user($user)){
            $message = '<div class="alert alert-success">Bienvenido '.$inputs['user'].'</div>';
            $array = array('success' => true, 'message' => $message);
        }
        else{
            $messages = '<div class="alert alert-success">El usuario '.$inputs['user'].' no existe</div>';
            $array = array('fail' => true, 'messages' => $messages);
        }
    }
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($array);
}
else{
    header("Location: ../index.php");
}
```

### log.php

```
<?php

function user($user){

    include 'conexion.php';
    $conexion = conectar();
    mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");


    $query = "Select * from user where username = '{$user}'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
    $total = mysqli_num_rows($result);


    if($total > 0){

        return true;

    }
    else{

        return false;

    }

}
```

### conexion.php

```
<?php 


function conectar(){

    error_reporting(0);

    $server = 'localhost';
    $user_db = 'root';
    $pass_db = '';
    $db = 'user';


    $conexion = new mysqli($server, $user_db, $pass_db, $db);

    if($conexion->connect_errno){

        echo 'Error de Conexion. Código de Error: '.$conexion->connect_errno;

    }
    else{

        return $conexion;

    }

}
```

### ajax.js

```
$('#formulario').on('submit', function(){

    $('#formulario .warn').remove();
    $('form input').removeClass('warning');

    var thisForm = $(this),
        url = thisForm.attr('action'),
        type = thisForm.attr('method'),
        data = thisForm.serializeArray();


        $.ajax({

            url: url,
            type: type,
            data: data,
            dataType:"json",
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function(response){

                if(response.error){

                    $.each(response.fields, function(index, value){

                        $('.' + index).hide().html('<span class="warn">' + value + '</span>').fadeIn(700);
                        $('#' + index).addClass('warning');

                    });

                }

                else if(response.success){

                    $('#formulario').fadeOut(700, function(){

                        $('#response').hide().html(response.message).fadeIn(700);

                    });

                }

                else{

                    $('#response').hide().html(response.messages).fadeIn(700);

                }



            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus){

                console.log(xhr);
                console.log(textStatus);

            }

        });


    return false;

});
```

---

I'm getting the following error in console:

> ajax.js:53: Object {readyState: 4, responseText:
>   "{"fail":true,"messages":"El
>   usuario aa no existe(the user aa doesn´t exist)</div>"}", status:
>   200, statusText: "OK"} ajax.js:54: parsererror

---

[image: That's what the console shows, i don't know how to get the http headers :(]

---

i got this from the console:

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 
    at Object.parse (native)
    at n.parseJSON (http://localhost/ajax/js/jquery2.js:4:6225)
    at zb (http://localhost/ajax/js/jquery2.js:4:8172)
    at z (http://localhost/ajax/js/jquery2.js:4:11629)
    at XMLHttpRequest. (http://localhost/ajax/js/jquery2.js:4:15507)

it seems i'm getting a malformed request, that's what i read in another question

Comment: what is the  *exact* error message?

Comment: just that parsererror, the console shows the json array with the validation messages, but they are not displayed in the screen, only the empty fields validation work properly

Comment: clearly we have a different definition of *exact*, copy and paste it.

Comment: ajax.js:53: 
 Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "{"fail":true,"messages":"<div class=\"alert alert-success\">El usuario aa no existe(the user aa doesn´t exist)<\/div>"}", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}
ajax.js:54:
 parsererror


that's what i get in the console

Comment: Are you purposefully using `crossDomain: true`?  And maybe try `data: JSON.stringify(data)`

Comment: the JSON.stringify(data) doesn't work dude, and the crossDomain property, i read that in a forum xd

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're hitting the `error()` callback and a parse error on line 54 of ajax.js where you have :

`console.log(textStatus);`

We need to get into your `success` callback. What is the HTTP status code returned to the browser? You can find this using Chrome tools or Firebug and looking at the response in your browser.

Your response JSON body appears to look like this:

`{
  "fail": true,
  "messages": "El usuario aa no existe(the user aa doesn´t exist)</div>"
}`

`messages` containing `El usuario aa no existe(the user aa doesn´t exist)</div>` -- is that actually a trailing `</div>` with no opening `<div>`?

**Important sidenote**: It looks like you're taking raw user input from request values and running it through your database in this statement: `"Select * from user where username = '{$user}'"`. This leaves you open to what's known as a [SQL Injection attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). A malicious attacker can use this to delete data from your database or select data you don't want exposed. You should switch to using [PDO + prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or to escaping the input data to prevent this.

Comment: yes, i'm hitting the error part, the http status is 200, in the $message the div has it's opening and closing tags, i don't know why the opening are not appearing, but i got rid of the div tag and i got the same result, parsererror, and you're right, i'm just testing this, i'm gonna be using pdo, prepared statements, bind parameters and all that, but this is just a test

Comment: for debugging purposes, can you update your ajax.js as follows: https://jsfiddle.net/davemaple/psxaopup/ and paste the results from the console?

Comment: success callback  ajax.js:19 
{"error":true,"fields":{"user":"Debes Ingresar tu Nombre de Usuario","pass":"Debes Ingresar tu Contraseña"}} ajax.js:22 error callback
ajax.js:23 {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"fail\":true,\"messages\":\"El usuario asadasdsdasd no existe\"}","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}

bassically the same when i complete the form, the error part is triggered

Comment: OK. I see now. It must be getting back invalid JSON in the second scenario. Is there any way you could take a look at the raw response in Firebug or Chrome tools and take a screenshot of the response body? Also -- can you grab all the headers returned?

Comment: and how do i upload the screenshot?

Comment: You can edit your question and add it there: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135483/how-can-i-add-a-screen-shot-into-my-question